# Angular: Detect when user has stopped typing

Tags: java, angular

I have a textbox as an input element and would like to know when the user has stopped typing to make REST call. I read some posts to use setTimeout on keyup; however, then user has stopped typing for a certain amount time, I see that the API is getting called numerous times (depending on the length of what is typed). Is there any other way to detect that the user has stopped typing to make an API call?

Comment: The typical way is to have the user click a button, or some similar control. The button click triggers the API call. If you are looking to implement something more along the lines of [typeahead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeahead), like Google's search field, then take a look at [debounce](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086) approaches to avoid, or at least reduce, multiple unwanted API calls.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, This will help you out for sure and it is very easy to use:-

[debounceTime](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounceTime)

debounceTime delays the value emitted by the source Observable for the time in milliseconds you specified as its parameter.

--index.ts--

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// elem ref
const searchBox = document.getElementById('search');

// streams
const keyup$ = fromEvent(searchBox, 'keyup')

// wait .5s between keyups to emit current value
keyup$.pipe(
  map((i: any) => i.currentTarget.value),
  debounceTime(500)
)
.subscribe((value) => {
  console.log('value is', value);
});
```

--index.html--

```
<input type="text" id="search" />
```

Now in the subscribe body you can make your api call.